# woocommerce REST API rating for a product id

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I'm having a peculiar problem.
I've setup woocommerce REST API and so far everything functions well, including when i'm making a review for a product.
The problem is when I try to retrieve the review back, it always says 'Invalid review ID'

To make it clear, when I do this REST command it works well, listing all the reviews i created before
    /wp-json/wc/v3/products/reviews/

however when i do 
    /wp-json/wc/v3/products/reviews/[product ID]

it will show the above mentioned 'Invalid review ID'

Tried combination with review ID itself, product ID, nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all reviews for product based on product id in woocommerce v3 API you need to call this endpoint:

```sh
/wp-json/wc/v3/products/reviews?product=ID
```

So you need to pass product ID as URL parameter. To get all reviews for product with id 15 you need to send request like this:

```sh
/wp-json/wc/v3/products/reviews?product=15
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually after half a day of tinkering, it turns out I had an extra parameter from the GET request.

I did a /wp-json/wc/v3/products/reviews/[reviewID]?id=xx&otherparameters

This causes the JSON rest to not detecting properly

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you think the id is the product_id but it is review_id:

/wp-json/wc/v3/products/reviews/[review ID] // it should end with review id

If you want to retrieve all reviews of a specific product you should use this endpoint:

'products/product_id/reviews'

for example in ionic angular you can do this (using v2 rest api):

```
this.WooCommerce = WC({
  url: "https://example.com",
  consumerKey: "ck_b#####################",
  consumerSecret: "cs_########################",
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v2'
})

  this.WooCommerce.getAsync('products/'+product_id+'/reviews').then((data)=>{
  console.log(JSON.parse(data.body))
  this.reviews = JSON.parse(data.body);
  console.log(this.reviews); // logging reviews to console

} , (err)=>{
  console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: 'products/product_id/reviews' this results in 404

Comment: Ok @RajeshVishnani, You should use v2 version of rest api to use this endpoint. I will edit my post. Thanks